# CI rule - combine only/changes with variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need a build job to run if there was a change in certain directories OR if a variable is set to true.

The following does not work

```
only:
changes:
  - some/dir/**/*
  - another/dir/**/*
variables:
  - $NIGHTLY_JOB == "true"
```

The above will run the job when NIGHTLY_JOB variable is true. The job does not run when there is code change in specified directories.

How to OR these two conditions in GitLab rules?

We cannot use 'rules:' directive, because elsewhere in our massive build script there is 'except'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual keys within `only:` are logically joined by `AND`. There is no way to change the logical evaluation of this.

You can either split this to multiple jobs with reciprocal `only:`/`except:` or you can use `rules:`.

For example:

```yaml
build_changes:
  extends: .some_common_base
  only:
    changes:
    - some/dir/**/*
    - another/dir/**/*
  except:
    variables:
      - $NIGHTLY_JOB != "true"

build_nightly:
  extends: .some_common_base
  only:
    variables:
      - $NIGHTLY_JOB == "true"
```

or use rules (preferred):

```yaml
rules:
 - if: $NIGHTLY_JOB == "true"
 - changes:
   - some/dir/**/*
   - another/dir/**/*
```

> We cannot use 'rules:' directive, because elsewhere in our massive build script there is 'except'

You can replace the use of both `only:` and `except:` with `rules:`.

For example, suppose you had:

```
only:
  variables:
    - $FOO == "true"
except:
  variables:
    - $NOBUILD == "true"
```

An equivalent rules would be:

```yaml
rules:
 # put the "except" rules first and set `when: never`
 - if: $NOBUILD == "true"
   when: never
 # then the "only" rules
 - if: $FOO == "true""
```